# Clustered Column Store Index gets created in the beginning and vanishes once the job is completed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have an existing application which has many SQL Server stored procedures that run as below.These stored procs are applied on a data file and compute is done as per some business rules.

```
1) Pre-process
2) Process 
3) Post-Process
```

In Pre-process, we are creating 'n' no. of tables with clustered column store index in place.  When the job kicks off the tables get created with clustered column store index but the indexes vanish once the job is completed. ( This happens only for a large input data file. )

When I run the job on a small data file the clustered column store index gets created on the tables and it exists even after the completion of job.

Note :- The code is the same when i executed it for both small and large data files.

Can somebody share your thoughts on this if you have encountered similar problem?

Comment: There is a problem in your code, but where it might be impossible to guess based on what you posted. Perhaps running a trace while the process is running will provide information.

Comment: Trace is producing millions of rows which is very tough to debug through.

Answer (score 0):

Two things will cause an already fully established Index to 'vanish' from a table:

1. A process or user deletes it.
2. The transaction in which the index was created is rolled back, either because an exception was raised later in the transaction, the transaction wasn't recoverable, or via an explicit Rollback.

And that's it. You're answer lies in one of the two above.

***I know this is not the answer you were looking for, it is however guaranteed to be THE answer. Somewhere your code is failing and that's why the indexes are now vanishing.***

Sql Server isn't a slapdash RDBMS - if it just arbitrarily just randomly dropped indexes then you know we'd be all over it. By your own admission you have complicated code.

Our DataWarehouse routinely drops and rebuilds indexes of all sorts - the only times it's 'missing' them has been the result of a bug in *our* code.

Comment: Why does it get created in case of a small data file?

Comment: That we cannot answer. Trust me, indexes do not randomly vanish. If they did then Enterprises the world over would be in a world of hurt. We cannot answer your question and more than I already have. Somewhere your code is failing. It's NOT Sql Server. Trust me. My thoughts have been given and similar issues have ALWAYS been down to user code. ALWAYS.